# application server from angular cli not able to reference style.css

Tags: angular

I am starting my angular application using angular cli using ng serve command.
The application is not able to serve the style.css file and I get a 404 on the browser.

My style.css and index.html are at the same level under the src folder.
In my index.html I am referencing style.css as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

**I also see that styles.css is referenced in angular-cli.json file**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

How do I figure out why I am getting a 404 when the app is trying to load styles.css

**below is my folder structure**

```
web/  
  angular-cli.json  
  src/    
    index.html
    styles.css    
  app/
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your project is compiled, all files in the `angular-cli.json` are bundled. It means they are all re-written in a vendor file, which changes name and is minified.

This is means that putting a reference to `style.css` in your `index.html` gives a 404, since the file doesn't exist anymore. Just remove the reference and you should be good to go.

Comment: So will my style.css be loaded because it is referenced in angular-cli.json file? How can I see in the browser whether it is loaded. I have infact imported bootstrap.css in my styles.css file but I dont see any of the css taking effect. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes it will be available. You can test it by simply calling your classes in the HTML, like you would do with bootstrap. it's rather hard to find it : open your Chrome console, go into the `Sources` tab, open the `main.bundle.js` file (either look for it iin the list or strike Ctrl+P), and search in document (Ctrl+F) for one of your classes.